# Отчет формируется пустым, при выполнения тестов в selenium (JUnit) при использовании framework allure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, allure

Тесты написаны в IntelliJ Idea. В POM.xml добавил:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>{latest-allure-version}</allure.version>
</properties>
```

В блок `dependencies`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.23</version>
</dependency>`
```

В блок `build`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Блок `reporting`:

```
<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsPattern>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsPattern>
                <reportVersion>1.4.14</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
               </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>`
```

Далее ввожу команду в терминал: `mvn clean test site`

[image: Смотрите скрин результаты команды]

Тест выполнился успешно, но при открытии отчета отображается текстовое сообщение выполнено 0 тестовых сценарий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего проблема в том, что используется разные версии отчета и адаптера. Попробуй изменить версию отчета в Мавен плагине на 1.4.23